# C++ help with headers

Tags: c++, header

I've got a C++ project and I'm really confused with the header organization in that project. I have header files for gui declaration and source files. The organization is:

```
//file1.h
#pragma once

//file1.cpp
#include "file1.h"

//file2.h
#pragma once

//file2.cpp
#include "file2.h"
```

And when I'm trying to inlcude file1.h in file2.h or file2.cpp and using file1.h types I always get the fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file. How resolve this problem.

I've created a simple project to illustrate the problem. [TestProject](http://depositfiles.com/files/s2xvwsr7g)

Comment: `file1.h` and `file2.h` exists in same directory?

Comment: Yes. They both are in the same directoy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file
```

Means most probably either your file is not present at the path or you have not added the path of the file to your include path.

Have a look at **[Fatal Error C1083](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et4zwx34%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**.

Comment: I forgot to add that the project uses the precompiled headers. It's an old project.